# 500 Internal Server Error with Wamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I've created a web service using php, slim and mysql but when I try to access the urls it gives me "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

When I check the log it gives me :

> C:/wamp/www/task_manager/.htaccess: Invalid command '.htaccess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I checked few things online and I can ensure you that rewrite_module is installed and activated (not commented in the http.config

does anyone know how to fix that? 
I ll attach the content of my .htaccess

```
.htaccess

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the line `.htaccess` from your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

if you install new wamp on your system, 
and you are using htaccess in your project to rewrite some urls first you need:

Click on wamp icon and Go to "Apache"  Then Click on "Apache Modules"

and make sure your **RE WRITE extension** should be checked.